# Websites link that have AWS integration

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am totally new to **Amazon web services**. Can you guys plz give me a url of a website(s) so that I can see the live usage of AWS. I have seached over google but didnt find such links.

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

There are many places to learn about Amazon Web Services, eg:

- http://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/ (Guided introduction)
- http://aws.amazon.com/training/intro_series/ (Introductory videos)
- http://cloudacademy.com/ (Online training, free trial available)
- http://qwiklabs.com/ (Self-paced labs, some are free)
- http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ (All documentation is public)
- http://www.youtube.com/user/AmazonWebServices (LOTS of videos!)